# it is possible in quartz to configure a job on one server and running that job on another server?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I wanted to put the schedule job in one server and  run jobs on another server can we assign job class of different application,

I am using JobStoreTX and use MySQL for data store.

**or**

is there any other way that we can call another application in java and schedule can be done there only?

I am using following quartz property file.

```
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties  

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: TestScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 1000
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5

# Configure JobStore  
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 300000 
org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties: false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource: myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: false

# Configure Datasources  
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bsviewer2
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
```

I am using following server for store in local table

```
package com.agileinfotech.bsviewer.servlet;


public class ScheduleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        try {



            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");


            HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
            String usrid = httpSession.getAttribute("userId") != null ? httpSession
                    .getAttribute("userId").toString() : "0";




            String txtJobName = request.getParameter("txtJobName");
            String schedule_type = request.getParameter("scheduleType");
            String onceDate = request.getParameter("oncejobDate");
            String onceTime = request.getParameter("oncejobTime");
            String rc_day = "";
            String[] rc_day1 = request.getParameterValues("sch_days");
            if (rc_day1 != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < rc_day1.length; j++) {
                    rc_day = rc_day + "," + rc_day1[j];
                }
                if (rc_day1.length > 1) {
                    rc_day = rc_day.substring(1);
                }
            }
            String rc_time = request.getParameter("recjobTime");
            String documentName = request.getParameter("documentName");
            String isDocFlag = request.getParameter("DocFlag");
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String emailCount = request.getParameter("cnter") != null ? request
                    .getParameter("cnter").toString() : "0";
            Date ffdate = null;
            Date once_time = null;
            Date recTime = null;
            HashMap paramMap = null;
            String documentFormat = "";

            if (schedule_type.equals("rightNow")) {
                jobStatus = tiggerJob.schedule_rightNow(all parameter);
            }
            if (schedule_type.equals("Once")) {
                jobStatus = tiggerJob.schedule_Once(ffdate, once_time, all parameter);
            }
            if (schedule_type.equals("Recurring")) {
                jobStatus = tiggerJob.schedule_Rec(recTime, rc_day, all parameter);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TriggerJob {

                    String jobStatus = "";
                    SchedulerMetaData metaData = null;

                    public String schedule_rightNow(HashMap ParamMap){  

                        try{
                            SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                            Scheduler sch = sf.getScheduler();
                            String txtjob=ParamMap.get("txtJobName").toString();
                            JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(txtjob, "Group1");
                            JobDetail job = newJob(JobSchedule.class).withIdentity(jobKey)
                                    .build();
                            long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
                            String sTimeStamp = String.valueOf(timestamp);
                            SimpleTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity(sTimeStamp, "Group1")
                                    .startNow().
                                    withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                                            .withIntervalInSeconds(1).withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                                            .build();
                            sch.getListenerManager().addJobListener(new ListernerTrigger(), KeyMatcher.keyEquals(jobKey));
                            job.getJobDataMap().putAll(ParamMap);
                            Date ft  = sch.scheduleJob(job,trigger);


                            sch.start();
                            Thread.sleep(5L * 1000L);
                            sch.shutdown(true);
                            metaData = sch.getMetaData();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return jobStatus;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: i just wanted to separate the things, 
configure jobs on one application and running them on another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This can be done by only starting the scheduler from another application.**
you can put following code in your another application.

```
    package packagename...;

    import java.io.File;
    import org.quartz.Scheduler;
    import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
    import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
    import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;


    public class ScheduleServer {

        public ScheduleServer() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {


                SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                Scheduler sch = sf.getScheduler();
                sch.start();

            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

And in your first application don't start the scheduler only assign the job class and other trigger.

```
public class TriggerJob {

                String jobStatus = "";
                SchedulerMetaData metaData = null;

                public String schedule_rightNow(HashMap ParamMap){  

                    try{
                        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                        Scheduler sch = sf.getScheduler();
                        String txtjob=ParamMap.get("txtJobName").toString();
                        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(txtjob, "Group1");
                        JobDetail job = newJob(JobSchedule.class).withIdentity(jobKey)
                                .build();
                        long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        String sTimeStamp = String.valueOf(timestamp);
                        SimpleTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity(sTimeStamp, "Group1")
                                .startNow().
                                withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                                        .withIntervalInSeconds(1).withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                                        .build();
                        sch.getListenerManager().addJobListener(new ListernerTrigger(), KeyMatcher.keyEquals(jobKey));
                        job.getJobDataMap().putAll(ParamMap);
                        Date ft  = sch.scheduleJob(job,trigger);


                        sch.start();
                        Thread.sleep(5L * 1000L);
                        sch.shutdown(true);
                        metaData = sch.getMetaData();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return jobStatus;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is a feature of the commercial version of quartz. What you can do is separating triggering form esecution. Use quartz to send a jms message to a server test will perform the job.

Comment: No, i think a quartz is open source to use.
and i just wanted to schedule my jobs on one server and running them to another.

Comment: Terracotta Quartz Scheduler Where is an Enterprise feature that allows jobs and triggers to run on specified Terracotta clients instead of randomly chosen ones. It is an extension of the open source project.http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/quartz-scheduler/quartz-scheduler-where

Comment: thnaks @ user2636900,
can you suggest me any other way i can do that, bcz i can not use the terracotta Quartz.

Comment: Use quartz just for the scheduling activation and use other techniques for distributed computetion. What I would do is: Quartz triggers a job that sends a JMS message. A JMS listener/MDB will receive the message and do the task. The MDB will be deployed at the server o instance you wish.